# MySQL Optimization for Queries with Functions in Where CLause

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-optimization

So let's assume I have an employee table (employee) and I have thousands of records in there. I need to limit the employees you can see based on your login for re-usability I create a function `fn_HasEmployeeAccess(t_userid int, t_employee_id INT)` that will return true/false to determine whether you have access to the employee or not.

This function looks something like this (although it does other checks, for example, you cannot access your own profile, you cannot access other employees that share a position with you etc):

```
 FUNCTION fn_HasEmployeeAccess(t_userid INT, t_employee_id INT)
             DECLARE isAdmin BOOL;
             DECLARE isDirector BOOL;
             DECLARE empStatus INT;

             SELECT admin, director INTO isAdmin, isDirector FROM users 
             WHERE users.userid=t_userid;

             /*select the status of this user if it is in your dept
             if employee is not in your department - status will be null 
             which will fail the checks below and return 0*/
             SELECT employee.status INTO empStatus FROM employee 
             INNER JOIN users ON employee.department = users.department
            WHERE employee.employeeID=t_employee_id;

             IF empStatus IN (1,2) AND isAdmin THEN
                     RETURN 1;
             ELSE IF empStatus=2 AND userIsDirector THEN
                     RETURN 1;
            ELSE
                     return 0;
            END IF;
    END FUNCTION
```

Now all of this works and is great, except when you have a lot of data and need to query using multiple joins and then on top of that filter based on the result of this function - the performance degrades quite a bit and I believe I understand - the function is being run for every row in the employee table.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM employee e
INNER JOIN employee_attachments a ON e.employeeID = a.employeeID
WHERE fn_HasEmployeeAccess(12345, e.employeeID)=1
```

How can I prevent what I would assume is full table scans due to the function usage? Are their alternatives to this pattern?

The function is used for filtering almost everywhere in the application (dashboards, views, reporting) etc and if I wanted to adjust access to an employee, I currently just have to adjust the function. It has been suggested I just inline all of this logic but everytime we add a status, or want to change access logic this would entail wading through the system to change every query, every report, every section pertaining to an employee.

Also - I have heard functions can take advantage of indexes but only if the functions are deterministic. Would a function like this be deterministic? Given the same employeeID and userID it should return the same result....unless the user changes from an admin to director...then the function would return a different result. Is this function deterministic or non deterministic?

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: Which table is `status` in?  Please qualify all column names when using a `JOIN`.

Comment: Sorry - status is in the employee table and represents if this is a Terminated Employee, Active employee etc. (employee.status) - Updated

Answer (score 2):

In a newer version of MySQL/MariaDB, you can create a Virtual (Computed) column and index it.  The new column would be populated via your function.  With that, don't call the function in the `WHERE` clause, simply use the new column.

If (when) you add a new status, do a suitable `ALTER TABLE` to rebuild the column and index.

Comment: I see. My Example was simplified. In actuality there are more scenarios than just adding a status. For example - if i add user A to facility A and user A is a "Admin". User A can see all employees in status 1,2,3,4 for employees in facility A. 

I think a computed column is a great idea but it would have to be recomputed everytime any of the corresponding sections change.

Can computed columns use functions or complicated queries, subqueries, etc as part of their computation?

Comment: I think it could involve a Stored Function, thereby complexity.  My Solution is similar to Brian's, but the implementation is different.

Comment: Do you have an example of a generated column using a procedure? I am not sure that is possible as I have not seen it. Furthermore, my procedure would require inputs as whether you have access to an employee depends on who YOU are logged in as well. This is generally passed in from the application e.g.

SELECT * FROM employee WHERE fn_HAsAccessToEmployee(:session_userid, employee.employeeid)=1

Comment: Updated the original question to have more detail with regards to the nature of the function. Thanks for your input so far Rick

Comment: The Stored Function (not Procedure) that you currently have is probably sufficient for defining the new column.  However, since it does reach into other tables with a `SELECT`, I am not sure if it will work.  Test it out!

Comment: Sorry - one thing with regards to that - the problem is that one of the inputs is a USERID. Which i only know once the user logs into my system. That is one of the challenges I am facing with regards to this as well. USERID is an application supplied variable so I am not sure how I would do this in a calculated column. Save for calculating every possible matrix of user->employee access.

Answer (score 1):

If I were facing this, I would calculate the result of the "Employee Has Access" call and store it (possibly encoded, for security) in the table directly, via an overnight process.  Then I'd attach a trigger to the fields that affect the results of "Employee Has Access" so that if the values get updated, the result gets recalculated.

Comment: Interesting approach and definitely one to consider. Thanks.

Comment: I think where this falls short though is that whether you have access to an employee is dependent on who YOU are as well as other factors (status etc). I dont think a column on the employee table would cut it - it would essentially have to be another table with:
loggedInUserID, employeeID, status, has_access

Comment: Perhaps - I didn't pick up on that in the initial post.  That said, I think Rick James' approach is probably better.

Comment: I am still trying to think this through. Calculated columns would be perfect if there wasnt a reliance on the logged in user etc. And in your approach, building a cache for every user of the system and who they have access to seems a bit much.

For example, I might have 1000 users and 50000 employees, am I going to create a user to employee index (i would assume this would be 1000 * 500000) in order to store the 1/0 flag? It seems like that wouldnt be the best path either. Trying to determine the best way around - thanks for your input so far.

Comment: On top of that I think maintining this matrix would be a nightmare (when a user has groups added this would have to change, when an employee is added to a facility this would have to be built for that employee, etc etc etc)